# Dynamically set selection of jcrop (not fixed selection)

Tags: php, jquery, crop, jcrop

I am working with a jcrop now I want to do something like here

```
       jQuery(function(){
            jQuery(".image_container .a-center h2").html("Upload another picture")
            var api;
            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
            bgOpacity: 0.5,
            bgColor: 'black',
            addClass: 'jcrop-dark',
            aspectRatio: 320/180,
            setSelect:[320,320,180,180],
            onSelect: updateCoords,
            onChange: updateCoords
          },function(){
            api = this;
            api.setOptions({ bgFade: true });
            api.ui.selection.addClass('jcrop-selection');
          });
        });
```

and it gives this kinda output on selection [image]

and I want this kind of selection upon 
[image]

what should I do to get max selection for width.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ratio = 1.2222222;
var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#modal-file-crop-image');
jcrop_api.setOptions({ aspectRatio: ratio });
var dim = jcrop_api.getBounds();
```

dim should hold an array of the image size

so like [380,180]

i use the following to center the crop area based on aspect ratio

```
var $img = $("#modal-file-crop-image");
var w = $img.width();
var h = $img.height();

$img.css({"width": w, "height": h})

var ratio = 1.2222222;
var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#modal-file-crop-image');
jcrop_api.setOptions({ aspectRatio: ratio });
var dim = jcrop_api.getBounds();
var x = 0, y = 0, x_ = dim[0], y_ = dim[1];

var x_r = (x_ / ratio) - y_;
var y_r = (y_ / ratio) - x_;

if (x_r > 0) {
    x = x_r / 2;
}
if (y_r > 0) {
    y = y_r / 2;
}

jcrop_api.setSelect([x, y, dim[0], dim[1]]);
```

in your case you would probably just set y to 0 all the time

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

It seems Like your main Image file is having bigger size the 320x180. You have select area of 320 x 180 which is smaller then your actual Image.

So Here what you can do is.

1. Calculate Area and set it up in your code. For this, calculate New Height / Width On the bases of Height and Width Of Image; taking other parameter as master. (e.g for your image in question, Master parameter is **Width** and you can find a new Height which is based on aspect ratio and master parameter.)
2. Setup area coordinates.

I think this will solve your issue.